# discord.py: variable server-info

Tags: discord.py

Hi I'm doing a command to get the server information and I'm looking in the API (recently discord.py program).
I just can't define some variables, I specifically send the variable code (the rest works perfectly).
I also looked for questions that could answer mine but I found different answers that did not satisfy my requests (in case there were I apologize)

```
async def serverinfo(ctx):
    author = ctx.author.name
    guild = ctx.guild
    name_server = guild.name
    icon_server = guild.icon_url
    create_server = guild.created_at
    owner_server = guild.owner.name
    total_member_server = guild.member_count

    #From here I can't find variables
    
    online_member_server = guild.online_members
    offline_member_server = guild.offline_members
    human_member_server = guild.memberUser
    bot_member_server = guild.member_bot
    total_channel_server = guild.channels
    text_channel_server = guild.text_channels
    vocal_channel_server = guild.voice_channels
    category_server = guild.categories
    total_role_server = guild.role_count
    boost_level_server = guild.level_boost
    number_boost_server = guild.boost
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your variables are valid, like `guild.member_count`, `guild.text_channels`, `guild.voice_channels`, `guild.channels` and `guild.categories` but you use them the wrong way. Except for `guild.member_count`, those properties return lists, not integer, so you need to use `len(property)` if you want the total number of them.

- Get the total [categories](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Guild.categories), [channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Guild.channels), [text_channels](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Guild.text_channels), [voice_channels](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Guild.voice_channels):

```py
channels_info = {
    "total categories": len(guild.categories)
    "total channels": len(guild.channels)
    "total text channels": len(guild.text_channels)
    "total voice channels": len(guild.voice_channels
}
```

- Get the [members](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild%20members#discord.Guild.members) informations:

```py
members_info = {
    "total users": guild.member_count
    "total online members": sum(member.status==discord.Status.online and not member.bot for member in ctx.guild.members)
    "total offline members": sum(member.status==discord.Status.offline and not member.bot for member in ctx.guild.members)
    "total humans": sum(not member.bot for member in ctx.guild.members)
    "total bots": sum(member.bot for member in ctx.guild.members)
}
```

- Get the [role](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=role#discord.Role) informations:

```py
roles_info = {
    "total roles": len(guild.roles)
}
```

- Get the server boosts informations ([premium tier](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Guild.premium_tier) and [premium_subscription_count](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Guild.premium_subscription_count)):

```
boosts_info = {
    "boost level": guild.premium_tier
    "total boosts": guild.premium_subscription_count
}
```

Comment: it worked but there is a problem ... it marks me all non-bot users online and 0 offline

Comment: Which line (or variable) ?

Comment: `online_member_server = sum(member.status!='offline' and not member.bot for member in ctx.guild.members)`
    `offline_member_server = sum(member.status=='offline' and not member.bot for member in ctx.guild.members)` returns all users in the online section and 0 in the offline ones

Comment: I don't really where the problem is ^^ `online_member_server` will give you all the non bots online members and `offline_member_server` will do the same but for offline members

Comment: I send you an image (it's written in Italian but the underlined part I think you understand in English) and below the code I used (the one recommended by you).
output:https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/732991857071489094/unknown.png
variable:https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/732992524481724526/unknown.png

Comment: I've edited the code, it should work now :) I forgot to use `discord.Status.online` and `discord.Status.offline`

Answer (score 0):

You have to turn on all the intents and use this in your code `fetch_offline_members=True` like this

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="c!",intents=intents,fetch_offline_members=True)
```