# Server information command discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am having some issues with my server-information command in discord.py. For the `premium_tier` (Boost) `if` calls, I am getting `Undefined variable 'premium_tier'`. I believe that I am getting an error for the thumbnail, though I am not seeing it.

Code:

```
@bot.command()
async def server(ctx, *, server: discord.Guild = None):
    embedVar = discord.Embed(color=0xfaa61a)
    date_format = "%a, %d %b %Y %I:%M %p"
    embedVar.add_field(name="Created at:", value=server.created_at.strftime(date_format))
    embedVar.add_field(name="Humans", value=sum(not member.bot for member in ctx.guild.members))
    embedVar.add_field(name="Bots", value=sum(member.bot for member in ctx.guild.members))

    if premium_tier == "0":
        embedVar.add_field(name="Boost Level", value='None')
    if premium_tier == "1":
        embedVar.add_field(name="Boost Level", value='1')
    if premium_tier == "2":
        embedVar.add_field(name="Boost Level", value='2')
    if premium_tier == "3":
        embedVar.add_field(name="Boost Level", value='3')
    
    embedVar.add_field(name="Owner", value=server.owner)
    embedVar.set_thumbnail(url=server.icon_url)
    return await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)
```

Comment: You would not be getting an error for the thumbnail (as far as I see) but you are getting an error for `premium_tier`. Have you defined premium_tier anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to define where you're getting the premium tier from. Also, you're reading the boosts as `string`s rather than `int`s.

```py
@bot.command()
async def tier(ctx, *, server: discord.Guild=None):
    if server == None: # don't mind this, it's to ensure it defaults to current guild
        server = ctx.guild

    await ctx.send(server.premium_tier) # this returns an int
```

This is how the above command would work:

[image: Blitz Server Boost]
[image: Another Server's Boost]

And this is how your command would look:

[image: Asker's Command]

Other Questions Like This:

- [SO: discord.py: variable server-info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62902610/14420546)
- [SO: Get the number of boosts in a server discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65385757/get-the-number-of-boosts-in-a-server-discord-py)